# link not working in html?

Tags: html, jsp

I am designing a web page and one of my link is not working...its even not working as a link..just looking like plain text...This is my code:

```
<a href="index.jsp" class="classname" style=" margin-top:50px;margin-left:1130px"> < </a>
            <a href="index.jsp" class="classname1" > > </a>
```

My url of link is correct if I place this anchor tag somewhere else in code the link works..but here it doesn't .I am new to web designing and don't know what is the error?Any IDEAs?
This is my full code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="ico/E-Mail.ico">

    <title>Mail Detective</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/hover.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="css/button.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <style>
        a, u {
                text-decoration: none;
            }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>

          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.jsp">Mail Detective</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">E-Mails</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="Search.jsp" method="get">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." name="search">

          <!--  a href="index.jsp"><input type="submit" value=login style="color: transparent; background-color: transparent; border-color: transparent; cursor: default;"></a-->
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li class="active"><a href="gmail_like.jsp">Inbox</a></li>
            <li><a href="Starred.jsp">Starred</a></li>
            <li><a href="Spam.jsp">Spam</a></li>
            <li><a href="Sentmail.jsp">Sentmail</a></li>
            <li><a href="Drafts.jsp">Drafts</a></li>
            <li><a href="Trash.jsp">Trash</a></li>
            <li><a href="Allmail.jsp">All</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <% int value=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("item"));%>
          <a href="index.jsp" class="classname" style=" margin-top:50px;margin-left:1130px";> < </a>
            <a href="index.jsp" class="classname1" > > </a>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main" style="margin-top:-60px">

          <h1 class="page-header">E-Mails</h1>

          <!--<div class="row placeholders">
          </div>!-->

          <!--<h2 class="sub-header"></h2>-->
              <!--NOTIFICATION STARTS-->
                <div class="col-lg-4" style="margin-left:850px">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <i class="fa fa-bell fa-fw"></i> Notifications Panel
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="list-group">
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                                    <i class="fa fa-comment fa-fw"></i> New Comment
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small"><em>4 minutes ago</em>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i> 3 New Followers
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small"><em>12 minutes ago</em>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> Message Sent
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small"><em>27 minutes ago</em>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                                    <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i> New Task
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small"><em>43 minutes ago</em>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                                    <i class="fa fa-upload fa-fw"></i> Server Rebooted
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small"><em>11:32 AM</em>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                                    <i class="fa fa-bolt fa-fw"></i> Server Crashed!
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small"><em>11:13 AM</em>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                                    <i class="fa fa-warning fa-fw"></i> Server Not Responding
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small"><em>10:57 AM</em>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-fw"></i> New Order Placed
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small"><em>9:49 AM</em>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                                    <i class="fa fa-money fa-fw"></i> Payment Received
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small"><em>Yesterday</em>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.list-group -->
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-block">View All Alerts</a>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-body -->
                    </div>
              <!--NOTIFICATION ENDS-->
          <div  class="table-responsive" style="margin-top:-530px;margin-left:-900px;font-size:15px;width:900px;background-color: #f5f5f5">

            <table class="table table-striped">

             <%@ page import="check.test4query"  %>
            <% test4query demo = new test4query();

            //out.println(value);
            test4query dem = new test4query();
            test4query de = new test4query();
            test4query d = new test4query();
            String[] id =new String[30];
            String[] dat =new String[30];
            String[] nam =new String[30];
            String[] mailid =new String[30];
            int i;
           demo.mai("SELECT ?x WHERE { ?y <FOLDERNAME:> 'inbox' . ?y <SUB:> ?x} LIMIT 30 OFFSET"+value);
           for(i=0;i<30;i++)
           {   id[i]=test4query.arr[i];
                id[i] = id[i].substring(0, Math.min(id[i].length(), 100));
           }
          dem.mai("SELECT ?x WHERE { ?y <FOLDERNAME:> 'inbox' . ?y <DATE:> ?x} LIMIT 30 OFFSET"+value);
           for(i=0;i<30;i++)
           {   dat[i]=test4query.arr[i];
                dat[i] = dat[i].substring(0, Math.min(dat[i].length(), 19));
           }
           de.mai("SELECT ?x WHERE { ?y <FOLDERNAME:> 'inbox' . ?y <SENDERNAME:> ?x} LIMIT 30 OFFSET"+value);
           for(i=0;i<30;i++)
           {   nam[i]=test4query.arr[i];
                nam[i] = nam[i].substring(0, Math.min(nam[i].length(), 16));
           }
           demo.mai("SELECT ?x WHERE { ?y <FOLDERNAME:> 'inbox' . ?y <MESSAGEID:> ?x} LIMIT 30 OFFSET"+value);
           for(i=0;i<30;i++)
           {   mailid[i]=test4query.arr[i];
                //mailid[i] = mailid[i].substring(0, Math.min(id[i].length(), 100));
           }

            for(i=0;i<30;i++)
            { //id[i]=test4query.arr[i];
                out.println("<tr height='5'><td width='120'style='font-size:15px'>"+nam[i]+"</td><td width='400'>"+"<a href='final.jsp?itemId="+mailid[i]+"' class='button grow' style=' text-decoration: none; color:black;font-size:15px;'>"+"&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"+id[i]+"<hr style='border-color:#E6E6E6;padding:0px;margin:0px'>"+"</a>"+"</td><td width='90' style='font-size:12px'>"+""+dat[i]+"</td>"+"</tr>");
            }i--;   
            %>

            </table>
          </div>


      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/docs.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *but here it doesn't* - where is *here*?

Comment: The code included has *two* links, and each of them works as such, though the link texts are just “ < ” and “ > ” and the links point to the same destination. So this is probably the result of something gone rather wrong, but we can’t know what without more information.

Comment: The links are working fine if I place somewhere else in my code ...

Comment: @cooljohny presently where have placed these links ??

Answer (score 0):

maybe you forgot an semicolon after margin-left:1130px;

Hope this could help

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer. Also, why do you think this would have any effect?

Comment: This does not change the output!!

Comment: I was not sure if that would effect the html itself. It was the first thing i saw which is not correct sorry for just giving a hint. It would affect the position and if there is a mistake in the code maybe the a tag would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Use instead <  for &lt; and > for &gt;
```

I use your HTML code also

```
<a href="index.jsp" class="classname" style=" margin-top:50px;margin-left:1130px"> < </a>
            <a href="index.jsp" class="classname1" > > </a>
```

It is also working... If it is not redirecting at proper place it means your path in href is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Use chrome developer tools to find out why.

1. Open the page in Chrome browser.
2. Press the F12 key.
3. Click on the Magnifying glass icon and click on the Link you want to investigate.
4. Look at the properties in the right panel to find the problem.

The basic point is that using CSS you can make links look like normal text. If you want to find out where this style is written you can use the developer tools as I've mentioned.